# Convergence and uniform boundedness

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to show that  $$\sum(-1)^n 
\frac{\sin[nx\pi]}{n}$$ converges and $$\frac{1}{e^{n^{2}\pi^{2}t}}$$ is uniformly bounded when $$0\le t\le t_{0}$$ for all n. for the first part which test you think I should use and i couldnt show the second part at all since when t is so small the expression is growing faster.

thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sine function is bounded above by $1$. So:

$$|\frac{sin[n\pi x]}{n}| \leq \frac{1}{n}$$.

I would use this bound and look at the alternating harmonic series.

For part (ii), since $[0, t_{0}]$ is compact, the function below achieves both a maximum and a minimum. This implies uniform boundedness:

$$\frac{1}{e^{n^{2} \pi^{2} t}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Then sequence
$$
a_n=\sin x+\sin 2x+\cdots+\sin nx,
$$
is bounded since
$$
a_n ={\mathcal Im}\, \big(\mathrm{e}^{ix}+\mathrm{e}^{inx}\cdots+\big)
={\mathcal Im}\,\frac{\mathrm{e}^{i(n+1)x}-\mathrm{e}^{ix}}{\mathrm{e}^{ix}-1}
$$
and hence for $x\ne 2k\pi
$$$
\lvert a_n\rvert \le \frac{2}{\lvert\mathrm{e}^{ix}-1\rvert},
$$
while $a_n=0$, for $x=2k\pi$.

Next the convergence of your series is a consequence of [Dirichlet's Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).

Answer (score 0):

For the first equation 
$$|\frac{sin[n\pi x]}{n}| \leq \frac{1}{n}$$

And we know by libenitz rule that if a series is going to zero and it is changing from positive to negative so it converges.

[From Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test)

Comment: Not true. The series is not alternating.

Comment: Why isn't it alternating because of (-1)^n ?

Comment: Because $\sin nx$ does not have a fixed sign!